# Rails 4.2.2 - How to create jstree dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jstree, ancestry

In rails 4.2.2, I am using `jstree` and `ancestry` gems for files structure. Right now I am able to generate the ancestry data but I am not able to access it in jstree function. I have referred from [this tutorial](http://tech.sunilnkumar.com/2014/03/28/tree-hierarchy-with-js-tree-and-ancestry/) . When I used the same example I got an error like below,

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `category_path' for #<Module:0x00000004b1cd40>):
app/models/category.rb:12:in `block in build_display_ancestry'
app/models/category.rb:7:in `each'
app/models/category.rb:7:in `build_display_ancestry'
app/models/category.rb:21:in `viewed_ancestry'
```

Model code is,

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :asset

  def self.build_display_ancestry(category_hierarchy, tailored_hierarchy_data = [])
    category_hierarchy.each do |category_data|
      state = category_data['children'].empty? ? 'leaf' : 'open'
      custom_display_data = {
        :data => category_data['name'],
        :state => state,
        :metadata => { href: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.category_path(category_data['id']) },
        :children =>  build_display_ancestry(category_data['children'], [])
      }
      tailored_hierarchy_data << custom_display_data
    end
    tailored_hierarchy_data
  end

  def self.viewed_ancestry
    build_display_ancestry(self.arrange_serializable, [])
  end

end
```

Controller code is,

```
class Users::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def view_ancestry
    render json: { data: 'Categories', state: 'open', metadata: { href: categories_path }, children: Category.viewed_ancestry }
  end
end
```

View is

```
<div id="category-hierarchy"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#category-hierarchy").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : $("#category-hierarchy").attr('data-path'),
            "data" : function (n) {
                return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
            }
        }
    },
    plugins : ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
    themes : {"theme": "default", "icons":false, "dots": true, "open":true},
    core: {"animation": 100}
   }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    if (jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href")) {
        window.location = jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href");
    }
  })
 });
</script>
```

Route is,

```
get 'users/categories/index' => 'users/categories#index', :as=> :categories
get 'users/categories/view_ancestry' => 'users/categories#view_ancestry', :as=> :users_categories_view_ancestry
```

Here, do I need to create `category_path` route   or not? If yes, what should be the action? Please help me to solve this issue and also give me some examples(with full code) link to refer.

Answer (score 1):

jsTree changed it's syntax, a lot, check on theres web page. i was able to pass (from same tutorial :)) this step by changing code from tutorial as:

```
.jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data': {
            'url' : '<some url>/<JSONdatasource>',
            'data' : function (n) {
                return { id : n.attr ? n.attr('id') : 0 };
            }
    }
  }
})
```

just follow (all the) changes on the web page, although very inconvinient i must say.

edit. note, although a question (as asked) indeed have problem with undefined method, the root/underlying problem at time of my answer is a changed syntax for JSON data for jsTree nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter `rake routes | grep categor` in your rails app directory, using your terminal to see which routes are available.

You probably should be using rails resource routes though:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
namespace :users do
  resources :categories do
    collection do
      get :view_ancestry
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: After changing it, error has solved but jstree structure is not loading. Please send me categories controller, view, model's full code